# Implements wild card dns on laravel

Tags: php, dns, laravel-5.5, laragon

After hours of research for the right keyword to implement a simple way of using wild card dns on laravel.

Here I'm using windows 10 and laragon.

This is the code I tried to implement in laravel route

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{account}.tindahan.local'], function() {
  Route::get('/page-one', function () {
    return view('welcome0');
  });
  Route::get('/page-two', function () {
    return view('welcome1');
  });
});
```

Base on the articles I read which you need to setup something like `*.domian.com` on vhost I have this automatically set in laragon

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot "C:/laragon/www/tindahan/public/"
    ServerName tindahan.local
    ServerAlias *.tindahan.local
    <Directory "C:/laragon/www/tindahan/public/">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I tried to visit `page-one.tindahan.local` on Chrome browser I got this message

> This site can’t be reached

I don't know what's missing of what I am doing. This is the first time I am doing something like this, so basically I don't have lots of idea.

Can you give me the right way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sure you should add entries to your hosts file (On windows usually `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`). For example you should have:

```
127.0.0.1 tindahan.local
```

for main domain, but you should also add other subdomains for example:

```
127.0.0.1 page-one.tindahan.local
127.0.0.1 page-two.tindahan.local
```

and so on

Comment: What I'm looking for is the implementation of something like in this article, https://www.quora.com/How-does-slack-create-DNS-for-teams-on-the-fly-like-teamname-slack-com. I wonder how can I do that simply with laravel.

Comment: Yes I understand but you asked what you have missed so you probably missed adding domains to hosts to test it on your local machine